# PYTHON: "While" To fill a dict with an increasing name and value

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I've been ripping my hairs out at this point... and searched the internet for answers and the best I've found was to make a separate file for the dictionary and import it when needed. However, me being very stubborn I want to fill this in python-style.

So, to quickly explain. I want to make a custom dictionary that makes X amount of entries into the dict, and the format is (for example) `{"Value_1": 1}` and the next entry will be `{"Value_2": 2}`. However if I wanted 100 entries I don't want to copy and paste the whole `.update` when the script starts but rather have a custom function where the `value_max` (refer to my code below) can be adjusted and a custom size pre-made dict is made. The name is to remain the same that part I dont need customized (just need the "_*increased_number_here*" part after the name), but I just want that dict to have the specified amount of entries. Alternative ways of achieving this are welcome, I want to then be able to pull a specific value lets say 80 and have it print "Value_80" (example). Thank you in advance!

Anyway here is my attempt which fails miserably:

```
value_max = 10
dict_point = 1
custom_dict = {}
current_value = 1
value_name = "Example"
value_number = 1 
value_num_str = str(value_number)

test_a = custom_dict
print(test_a)

while dict_point <= value_max:
    custom_dict.update({value_name + value_num_str:current_value})
    value_number += 1
    current_value += 1
    dict_point += 1

test_b = custom_dict
print(test_b)
```

> > > Output of test_a is `{}`
> > >       Output of test_b is `{Example_1:10}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you need to use so many variables to keep track of things. This is my simplified code that does what you want

```
value_name = "Example"
custom_dict = {}
dict_point = 1
value_max = 10

while dict_point <= value_max:
    custom_dict[value_name + "_{}".format(dict_point)] = dict_point
    dict_point += 1

test_b = custom_dict
print(test_b)
```

Comment: That works the best out of all the answers and it's very simple thanks! It works wonders. Could you please just explain to me how does the custom_dict[...] = Dict_point works because I don't get why that works so well... Thanks!!!

Comment: In most languages, the string between the square brackets "[" and "]" are keys used for accessing items in a dictionary. So in this case, we set the key and its value every time through the loop and since python allows you to create new item if it doesn't already exist, we are able to do what we've done above. The "{}" braces are used for substitution in a string. We could've done this as well: custom_dict["{}_{}".format(value_name, dict_point)] = dict_point

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, definitely will come in handy again in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to convert the `value_number` to string again so it kept on updating the same values.

```
value_max = 10
dict_point = 1
custom_dict = {}
current_value = 1
value_name = "Example"
value_number = 1 
value_num_str = str(value_number)

test_a = custom_dict
print(test_a)

while dict_point <= value_max:
    custom_dict.update({value_name + value_num_str:current_value})
    value_number += 1
    value_num_str = str(value_number)
    current_value += 1
    dict_point += 1

test_b = custom_dict
print(test_b)
```

Comment: That was simple thanks I will keep that in mind for future projects! Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You define `value_num_str` once, at the top of your code. At that moment `value_num_str` point to the string `"1"`.

You need to make the assignment `value_num_str = str(value_num)` inside the while loop - or, more effectively, do it inside the `update` call. Otherwise its value will never change. And since the `update` method replace dictionary entries if the key already exists, you end up with the same one entry in the dictionary.

Simply writing the `update` line as

```
custom_dict.update({value_name + str(value_num):current_value}) value_number += 1
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, answer below and above solved the problem for me but I will keep this in mind when coding future projects. Thank you for the answer ^-^